# OpenId with IdentityServer4

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am working on a project where we would like to use IdentityServer4 as a token server and have other services authenticated within this token server. I have dev env on Windows using Docker and linux containers. I configured IdentityServer and it's working, I configured Api client and it's working but, when I configured MVC client to authenticate, it's failing to access token server through docker. OK, I realized that Docker works in a way of having external/internal ports, so I configured the api and mvc client this way.

**MVC Client**

```
services.AddAuthentication(opts =>
{
    opts.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    opts.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddCookie("Cookies", opts =>
{
    opts.SessionStore = new MemoryCacheTicketStore(
                        configuration.GetValue<int>("AppSettings:SessionTimeout"));
})
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", opts =>
{
    opts.ResponseType = "code id_token";
    opts.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    opts.ClientId = "Mvc.Application";
    opts.ClientSecret = "Secret.Mvc.Application";
    opts.Authority = "http://authorization.server/";

    //opts.Authority = "http://localhost:5001/";
    //opts.MetadataAddress = "http://authorization.server/";

    opts.UsePkce = true;
    opts.SaveTokens = true;
    opts.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    opts.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    opts.Scope.Add("offline_access");
    opts.Scope.Add("Services.Business");
    opts.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("website", "website");
});
```

This part is working, because document discovery is working. **However it'll fail to access http://authorization.server url**, because it's internal container address, not external accessible through web browser. So I tried to set 2 different urls: MetadataAddress from which document from OpenId server should be fetched and Authority, where all Unauthorized requests are redirected. However when I set both MetadataAddress and Authority in OpenIdConnectOptions when calling AddOpenIdConnect, it'll use MetadataAddress instead of Authority. I checked logs, discovery of document is successfull, because I'm hitting http://authorization.server/.well-known..., but it's also initiating request to the IdentityServer to authenticate with the same url http://authorization.server/connect...

**Api Client**

```
services.AddAuthorization()
        .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(opts =>
        {
            opts.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            opts.ApiName = "Api.Services.Business";
            opts.ApiSecret = "Secret.Api.Services.Business";
            opts.Authority = "http://authorization.server/";
        });
```

This it's working fine using the internal container address.

**IdentityServer configuration**

```
services.AddIdentityServer(opt =>
{
    opt.IssuerUri = "http://authorization.server/";
})
.AddAspNetIdentity<User>()
.AddSigningCredential(Certificate.Get())
.AddProfileService<IdentityProfileService>()
.AddInMemoryApiResources(Configuration.ApiResources())
.AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Configuration.IdentityResources())
.AddInMemoryClients(Configuration.Clients());
```

**Configuration.cs**

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients(string redirectUri, string allowedCorsOrigins)
{
    return new List<Client>
    {
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "Services.Business",
            ClientName = "Api Business",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
            AllowedScopes = 
            { 
                "Services.Business"
            },
            ClientSecrets = 
            { 
                new Secret("Secret.Services.Business".Sha256()) 
            }
        },              
        new Client
        { 
            ClientId = "Mvc.Application",
            ClientName = "Mvc Application",                    
            RequireConsent = false,
            AllowOfflineAccess = true,
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,
            AllowedScopes =
            {
                "Services.Business",
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile
            },
            ClientSecrets =
            {
                new Secret("Secret.Mvc.Application".Sha256())
            },
            RedirectUris = 
            { 
                $"{redirectUri}/signin-oidc"
            },
            PostLogoutRedirectUris = 
            {
                $"{redirectUri}/signout-callback-oidc"
            }
        }
    };
}
```

**Docker-compose.yml**

```
    version: '3.4'

networks:
  fmnetwork:
    driver: bridge

services:
  authorization.server:
    image: authorization.server
    container_name: svc.authorization.server
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Authorization.Server/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
      - "5100:443"
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT: 5100
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Staging
      ASPNETCORE_URLS: "https://+;http://+"
      ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password: "devcertaspnet"
      ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path: /root/.dotnet/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    depends_on:
      - sql.server
    volumes:
      - D:\Docker\Data\Fm:/root/.dotnet/https
      - D:\Docker\Data\Fm\Logs:/Fm.Logs
    networks:
      - fmnetwork

  services.business:
    image: services.business
    container_name: api.services.business
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services.Business/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5001:80"
      - "5101:443"
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Staging
      ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT: 5101
      ASPNETCORE_URLS: "https://+;http://+"
      ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password: "devcertaspnet"
      ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path: /root/.dotnet/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    depends_on:
      - sql.server
    volumes:
      - D:\Docker\Data\Fm:/root/.dotnet/https
      - D:\Docker\Data\Fm\Logs:/Fm.Logs
    networks:
      - fmnetwork

  mvc.application:
    image: mvc.application
    container_name: svc.mvc.application
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Mvc.Application/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5002:80"
      - "5102:443"
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Staging
      ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT: 5102
      ASPNETCORE_URLS: "https://+;http://+"
      ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password: "devcertaspnet"
      ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path: /root/.dotnet/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    volumes:
      - D:\Docker\Data\Fm:/root/.dotnet/https
      - D:\Docker\Data\Fm\Logs:/Fm.Logs
    networks:
      - fmnetwork
```

Answer (score 4):

I just faced this same issue and was able to solve it as follows.

Some things to keep in mind:

- This is not an issue with Identity Server itself but with the mismatch between the internal Docker URL (`http://authorization.server`) that your container sees and the local host URL (`http://localhost:5001`) that your browser sees.
- You should keep using the local URL for Identity Server (`http://localhost:5001`) and add a special case to handle the container to container communication.
- The following fix is *only* for development when working with Docker (Docker Compose, Kubernetes), so ideally you should check for the environment (`IsDevelopment` extension method) so the code is not used in production.

### IdentityServer configuration

```cs
services.AddIdentityServer(opt =>
{
    if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        // It is not advisable to override this in production
        opt.IssuerUri = "http://localhost:5001";
    }
})
```

### MVC Client

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(... /*Omitted for brevity*/)
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", opts =>
{
    // Your working, production ready configuration goes here

    // It is important this matches the local URL of your identity server, not the Docker internal URL
    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5001";

    if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        // This will allow the container to reach the discovery endpoint
        opts.MetadataAddress = "http://authorization.server/.well-known/openid-configuration";
        opts.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

        opts.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
        {
            // Intercept the redirection so the browser navigates to the right URL in your host
            context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = "http://localhost:5001/connect/authorize";
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    }
})
```

You can tweak the code a little bit by passing said URLs via configuration.

Comment: This answer solved my issue with the internal open-id config! thank you very much!